# Summing integers in python list but excluding the number 13 and the number directly after it

Tags: python, list, function, sum

How would I make a better function than what I have?

```
def sum13(nums):
    total = 0
    wheresNumAfter13 = nums.index(13) + 1
    numAfter13Value = nums[wheresNumAfter13]
    for num in nums:
        if num != 13:
            total += num
    return total - numAfter13Value

print(sum13([1,2,3,4,5,13,4]))
```

Comment: You asking excatly what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the sum of the relevant slice, similar to what you're doing, look for the index of 13, and then do the sum for the parts of the list before it and after the next element to 13.

You can also use the built-in `sum` function on the resulting list of combining both parts:

```
def sum13(nums):
    wheres13 = nums.index(13)
    return sum(nums[0:wheres13]+nums[wheres13+2:])
```

Note this solution, like yours, only works for the case where you only have a 13 to exclude in the list.

Also they will fail if the list doesn't contain 13.

---

Explanation, for an example list like: `[1,2,3,4,5,13,4,10]`:

- Look for 13: `wheres13 = nums.index(13)`
- Get the part of the list before the index of 13: `nums[0:wheres13]`. This produces a list like `[1,2,3,4,5]`, i.e. from index 0 to index `wheres13` (not including it).
- Get the part of the list after 13: `nums[wheres13+2:]`. This produces a list like `[10]`, i.e. from the index of the number after the number after 13 (which has index `wheres13` plus 2), to the end of the list.
- Join both lists: `nums[0:wheres13]+nums[wheres13+2:]`. This produces a list like `[1,2,3,4,5,10]`
- Use python's builtin `sum` function on the list from the previous point

---

For completeness, heres a version modified to remove *every* 13 and next number:

```
def sum13(nums):
    n=nums
    while 13 in n:
        wheres13 = n.index(13)
        n = n[0:wheres13]+n[wheres13+2:]
    return sum(n)
```

Comment: Would you please be able to explain the third line in your answer? It works fine, I'm just unsure how.

Answer (score 2):

I'd be tempted to write this as a simple-ish generator comprehension. This works even if there are multiple instances of 13s:

```
>>> x = [1,1,1,13,99,1,1,13,99,1,13,13,13,1]
>>> sum(cur for cur,prev in zip(x, [None]+x) if 13 not in (cur,prev))
6
```

Read: sum up all of the numbers `cur` for which `cur` or the previous number aren't 13.

Maybe writing it as a generator function is more readable, though:

```
def exclude_13s(x):
    for cur,prev in zip(x, [None]+x):
        if 13 not in (cur,prev):
            yield cur
```

So that

```
>>> sum(exclude_13s(x))
6
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def sum13(nums):
    if 13 in nums:
        index13 = nums.index(13)
        del nums[index13:index13 + 2]
        return sum13(nums)
    else:
        return sum(nums)

print(sum13([1,2,3,4,5,13,4]))
```

Comment: Does this also exclude the num after 13?

Comment: This excludes every number after 13

Comment: Yes. I think that's what you want? Could you explain me what is actual requirement?

Comment: @hariK they want to exclude the number 13 and whatever number comes right after it. So if the list was `[1,13,4,10]`, 13 and 4 would be excluded, but 1 and 10 would not.

Answer (score 1):

> You can try this way too:

```
def The13(l):
    size = len(l)
    bucket = [y for x in range(size) for y in range(x,x+2) if(l[x]==13)]
    return sum([l[x] for x in range(size) if x not in bucket])
```

> bucket contains all indexes of element having 13 and the number directly after it

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without having to use `list.index` or worrying if `13` is present or not:

```
from itertools import takewhile, islice

def sum13(iterable):
    it = iter(iterable)
    return sum(takewhile(lambda L: L != 13, it)) + sum(islice(it, 1, None))
```

This will sum up until, but not including 13, then resume summing from the iterable ignoring the number immediately after 13.